# Find the class with a specific class const

Tags: php

I've got a number of product classes which extend a parent product class. Each of these implements its own version of a PRODUCT_ID const. A method in a customer object will pull the PRODUCT_ID 's from the DB. I'd then like to instanciate the relevant product object and add it to an array.

Any ideas how I can dynamically find out which product object has the specific PRODUCT_ID const?

Sorry if that is a bit confusing!

Comment: You can only have one constant per class NAME, not class instance. So with your method you will only be able to have one product instantiated per object. Is that what you want?

Comment: Not sure Clint. All of the product classes are named differently. i.e. product1, product2, product3. All extend product but all have their own version of the class const PRODUCT_ID. I just want to dynamically find out which one has a particular PRODUCT_ID value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to first loop through all of the declared classes, then check if they're a subclass of the parent product and finally to check if the PRODUCT_ID constant is defined and equal to the product you're looking for.

**Here an example:**

```
<?php

class Product
{
}

class Stack extends Product
{
  const PRODUCT_ID = 1;
}

class Overflow extends Product
{
  const PRODUCT_ID = 2;
}

function getSubclasses($parentClassName)
{
    $classes = array();
    foreach (get_declared_classes() as $className)
    {
        if (is_subclass_of($className, $parentClassName))
            $classes[] = $className;
    }

    return $classes;
}

function find_product($product_id)
{
  foreach ( get_declared_classes() as $class )
    if ( is_subclass_of($class, 'Product') )
      if ( constant($class . '::PRODUCT_ID') == $product_id )
        return $class;
}

echo find_product(1); // Outputs "Stack"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create class with field $product_id and accessors:

```
class Product
{
    protected $product_id;

public function __construct($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

    public function getProductId()
    {
        return $this->product_id;
    }

    public function setProductId($product_id)
    {
        $this->product_id = $product_id;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
$t = new Product(1254899);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each PRODUCT_ID value corresponds to a unique product class name, right ? So you can't have a PRODUCT_ID without a class associated ? So, in this case, you know how many product class you have.
If everything is true, I think the best solution is to create an array like this

```
$pairs = array(
    PRODUCT_ID_VALUE_ONE => 'classNameOne',
    PRODUCT_ID_VALUE_TWO => 'classNameTwo',
    // [...]
);
```

Then, when you want to retrieve the class name associated with a specific PRODUCT_ID, you have to do

```
    $className = $pairs[ $myProductId ];
```

You have two solutions to construct that array:

- build it manually,
- build it using automatically [PHP reflexion](http://php.net/ReflectionClass) (as shown by Francois)

If you have few class and if they don't change a lot, the first solution is better: its faster, easy to read/change values, easy to understand the code, and you have a better control over the array values => you set them manually so you won't have wrong values.

The problem with the first solution is you may have inconsistencies between the array and all the products class: if you change a PRODUCT_ID value into a class, you'll have to change it manually into the array.

The second solution is better if you have a lot of classes or if they change often. However, PHP reflexion may slow down your application. To limit that side effect, you can:

- build the array once and only once,
- build the array once only when needed,

You can create a method like `getProductClassById` which will:

- check the existence of the array above,
- created the array if necessary,
- search in that array,
- return the value,

Hope this will help,

Cheers

Comment: Thank you pomeh, very helpful! I had thought of something similar to the first solution but I don't want to hard-code anything. I know it may be slower but I'm only talking a handful of products (5 at the moment) and they are subject to constant change so I think the more dynamic the solution the better.